# How to create a Rule to add a menu link to a node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I create a Rule (with Rules) that will add a menu link to a node within a given menu.

I want to include this action in a VBO view... I have few hundreds node to update, but they're not all going at the same place.

thanks

Comment: Is it required that you use the Rules module? I think there might be other modules that could help..

Comment: I want to include this action in a VBO view... I have few hundreds node to update, but they're not all going at the same place

Comment: similar question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32505/bulk-node-menu-link-change-in-drupal-7) but with no answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the http://drupal.org/project/menu_link module?  Please provide your scenario and I would be glad to help